# A continuous path between two Sobolev functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open bounded, smooth boundary. Let $u_1$, $u_2\in H^{1}(\Omega)$ such that $T[u_1]=T[u_2]=T[\omega]$ where $T$ stands for the trace operator and $\omega\in H^1(\Omega)$ is a fixed function.

Define
$$
F(u):=\inf_{v\in\mathcal V}\left\{\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2v^2dx + \int_\Omega |\nabla v|^2+(1-v)^2dx \right\},
$$
where $\mathcal V:=\{v\in H^1(\Omega),\,0\leq v\leq 1\}$.

Question: does there exist a continuous path $a(t): [0,1]\to H^1(\Omega)$ between $u_1$ and $u_2$ satisfies the following conditions?

1. $a(0)=u_1$, $a(1)=u_2$
2. $T[a(t)]=T[\omega]$ for all $t\in (0,1)$
3. $a(t)$ is continuous in $L^2$ sense, i.e., if $t\to t_0$, then $a(t)\to a(t_0)$ in $L^2$.
4. $F(a(t))\leq \max\{F(u_1),F(u_2)\}$, for all $t\in (0,1)$.

Moreover, if $F(u_1)\leq F(a(t))\leq F(u_2)$ would be great, but it is not necessary... (here we assume $F(u_1)\leq F(u_2)$)

I tried the affine connection, i.e., $a(t)=tu_2+(1-t) u_2$, but it does not seems to work....

Any help, hint, or reference would be really welcome!

Comment: Why doesn't the affine path work? Seems to work to me... Moreover $\nabla\alpha_t=t\nabla u_2+(1-t)\nabla u_1$ and the convexity of the norm squared even gives you 4. and the additional condition you want.

Comment: @Teri: here the post is updated.

Comment: @Teri: I edit the problem a bit more. Now it is definitely a non-trivial problem...

Comment: Note that the compactness properties of $H^1(\Omega)$ imply that the infimum is attained. Using this one can still prove that $F$ is a convex functional, i.e. $F(tu_2+(1-t)u_1)\le tF(u_2)+(1-t)F(u_1)$. Property 4. and the additional condition always follow from this convexity.

Comment: @Teri Can you be more specific and write your comments as an answer? Thank you!

Comment: @Teri especially why $F$ is convex?

Answer (score 1):

I've to admit that my original argument had a (stupid) mistake. However the argument below should work.

First let me relabel: call the two functions $u_1,u_2$ by $u_0,u_1$ so as to be compatible with $u_t:=tu_1+(1-t)u_0$.

Note that given any $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, the infimum in $$F(u)=\inf_{v\in \mathcal V}\{\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2v^2 dx+\int_\Omega(|\nabla v|^2+(1-v)^2)dx\}$$ is obtained: take a minimizing sequence for $F(u)$ and, using the [Rellich-Kondrachov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem), find $v\in \mathcal V$ and a subsequence $v_k$ so that $v_k\to v$ in $L^2$, $\nabla v_k\rightharpoonup \nabla v$ weakly in $L^2$, and $v_k\to v$ pointwise almost everywhere. Then
\begin{align*}
F(u)\le &\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2v^2 dx+\int_\Omega(|\nabla v|^2+(1-v)^2)dx\\
\le &\liminf_{k\to\infty}\left[\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2v_k^2 dx+\int_\Omega(|\nabla v_k|^2+(1-v_k)^2)dx\right]=F(u).
\end{align*}

Now let $w_j$ be a function in $\mathcal V$ for which the infimum $F(u_j)$ is attained, $j=0,1$, and let $w_t=tw_1+(1-t)w_0$. By the edit below $$t\mapsto w_t^2|\nabla u_t|^2$$ is convex so we may estimate
\begin{align*}
F(u_t)\le & \int_\Omega |\nabla u_t|^2w_t^2 dx+\int_\Omega(|\nabla w_t|^2+(1-w_t)^2)dx\\
\le & t\int_\Omega|\nabla u_1|^2w_1^2dx+(1-t)\int_\Omega |\nabla u_0|^2w_0^2dx\\
&\ \ + t\int_\Omega(|\nabla w_1|^2+(1-w_1)^2)dx+(1-t)\int_\Omega(|\nabla w_0|^2+(1-w_0)^2)dx\\
=&tF(u_1)+(1-t)F(u_0).
\end{align*}
Thus $F$ is convex and this gives you the properties you want.

**EDIT:** Denote $$f(t)=f_x(t)=|\nabla u_t(x)|^2, g(t)=g_x(t)=w_t(x)^2.$$ Both are convex functions, but this alone doesn't guarantee the convexity of their product. Instead we use the fact that they are essentially quadratic.

Let us show that $(fg)''(t)\ge 0$. Compute
\begin{align*}
f'(t)=&2\nabla(u_1-u_0)\cdot \nabla u_t\\
g'(t)=&2(w_1-w_0)w_t\\
f''(t)=& 2|\nabla(u_1-u_0)|^2\\
g''(t)=& 2(w_1-w_0)^2.
\end{align*}
Next check that
\begin{align*}
(fg)''(t)&=f''(t)g(t)+2f'(t)g'(t)+g''(t)f(t)\\
=&2[|\nabla(u_1-u_0)|^2w_ t^2+4w_t\nabla(u_1-u_0)\cdot (w_1-w_0)\nabla u_t+(w_1-w_0)^2|\nabla u_t|^2]\\
\ge& 2(|\nabla(u_1-u_0)|w_t-|w_1-w_0||\nabla u_t|)^2-4|w_1-w_0|w_t|\nabla(u_1-u_0)||\nabla u_t|\\
\ge & 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: you mean that $w_t^2$ and $|\nabla u_t|^2$ is nonnegative and nondecreasing so that the product is convex? Since generally the product of nonnegative convex functions may not convex. However, we have $w_t^2$ is convex but $\nabla u_t$ may not be positive always.

Comment: I mean, why the function $|\nabla u_t|^2w_t^2$ is convex? We usually need $|\nabla u_t|^2$ and $w_t^2$ have nonnegative or nonpositive derivative at the same time. But I don't think we have in this case.

Comment: @tankonetoone You're right, the convexity of the product needs a separate argument, it doesn't follow automatically. I've made an edit to my answer to deal with this.

Comment: Sorry if this question is naive. But how you obtain the last inequality? You are basically saying that $(|a|-|b|)^2-2|ab|\geq 0$, which is not true in generally. For example, take $a=b$.

Comment: @tankonetoone You're right, again. I'm busy with a lot of stuff currently (hence the slow replies) but I'll try to see if anything can be done about the question. It seems that the convexity of $w_t^2|\nabla u_t|^2$ does not necessarily hold..